# Why doesn't return default(T?) give a null when T is constrained to enum?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a parser that render text files into a datamodel. Some fields are optional, which are to be represented as null in the model.

However, a strange behavior is giving me a headache. When I handle nullable concretely, it behaves as expected.

```
Foo? a = null;
```

...works just fine.

```
Foo? b = default(Foo?);
```

...works also just fine. b is null.

However, whenever I wrap this inside a generic class, it seems that it has a difficulty treating the generic type parameter in the same way.

```
void Main()
{
    Foo? is_null = null;
    Foo? is_also_null = default (Foo?);

    Foo? does_not_work = FooClass.GetNull<Foo>();
    Foo? is_not_null = FooClass.GetDefault<Foo>();   // Should be null, AFAICT, but isn't,
    
}

public static class FooClass
{
    public static T? GetNull<T>() where T:System.Enum
    {
        return null;  //Compile error: CS0403 Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.
    }
    public static T? GetDefault<T>() where T : System.Enum
    {
        return default(T?); // Why does this not return null? Shouldn't this be the same as default(Foo?) ?
    }
}

public enum Foo
{
    one,two,three
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I missing here?

Comment: If you add a struct constraint, it works: `GetDefault<T>() where T : struct, System.Enum`

Comment: I think that if T is an Enum, never can be null and default(T?) never will be null. When you try to return null, you are trying to cast your enum to null and get the error because compiler knows that your T can't be null. When you use "Foo?" you aren't using an Enum, you are using a Nullable<Enum>, that can be null.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

enum constraints basically: don't work as you expect; the `T : Enum` doesn't mean it is treating it *as a primitive* - it is treating it as a boxed value (object) instead, that happens to be a sub-type of the `Enum` type (or `Enum` itself!). Emphasis: keep in mind that you could have used `GetDefault<Enum>` here.

The `T?` won't even compile without a compiler that supports *Nullable Reference Types*, and with NRT support and NRTs disabled: it will give you a CS8632 warning; this means that `T?` here refers to NRTs, and **not** `Nullable<T>`. You can fix this by adding the `T : struct, Enum`, but without that: `default(T?)` is just the same thing as `default(T)` (because the `?` for NRTs doesn't change the type semantics - just whether we expect nulls or not), and `default(T)` is the zero enum.