# Non-nullable enum as generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, enums, non-nullable

I am trying to implement this helper function in C# 7.3:

```
public static T? ToEnum<T>(this string enumName)
    where T : Enum 
    => Enum.TryParse<T>(enumName, out T val) ? val : null;
```

But got a compiler error:

> Error CS8370 Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3

Why does the compiler think I am using a nullable reference type while T is constrained to be an `Enum` which is a value type already?

Comment: Enums are not reference types so the question you're asking doesn't apply. You just need to add the constraint `where T: struct`. This has been the case  for over a decade

Comment: While enums themselves are value types, `Enum` is a class and that's what you're using in your constraint, so that's presumably the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why doesn't return default(T?) give a null when T is constrained to enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170047/why-doesnt-return-defaultt-give-a-null-when-t-is-constrained-to-enum)

Comment: Any reason `System.Enum` has to be a class instead of a struct? @user18387401

Comment: @XiaoguoGe Because [nearly everything is an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436218/8967612). See also [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682604/8967612) by Eric Lippert for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is not specific to *nullable* enums. Even if you use a non-nullable enum, it won't work. That's because while specific enum types are value types, `System.Enum` is a reference type as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561365/8967612). So, you need to add a `struct` constraint *in addition to* the `Enum` constraint.

The following should work:

```
public static T? ToEnum<T>(this string enumName) 
    where T : struct, Enum
    => Enum.TryParse<T>(enumName, out T val) ? val : default(T?);
```

Also, note that you can't use `null` in the second branch of the ternary operator because the compiler can't infer the type. Use `default(T?)` instead.

**Example of usage:**

```
enum MyEnum { a, b, c }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var e1 = "b".ToEnum<MyEnum>();
    var e2 = "d".ToEnum<MyEnum>();

    Console.WriteLine("e1 = " + (e1?.ToString() ?? "NULL"));  // e1 = b
    Console.WriteLine("e2 = " + (e2?.ToString() ?? "NULL"));  // e2 = NULL
}
```

Comment: Should actually be `default(T?)` or just `null` otherwise it's going to be the `0` value of the enum