# default(T?) does not return null when T is a value type

Tags: c#, linq, default, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I've come across the following phenomenon and am absolutely bamboozled. I'm using C# 10 with nullables enabled.

`default(int?)` returns null as expected. The following function, however, returns whatever `default(T)` is

```
public static T? ShouldReturnNull<T>()
{
    return default(T?);
}
```

In the case of `ShouldReturnNull<int>()` we get 0. Shouldn't it also return null?

I have the following code in my program where this becomes an issue:

```
public T?[] FindKElements(...)
{
    var result = new (T, double)?[k];


    // ... populate result array,
    // possibly including null values...


    // return an array containing only the T part or null
    return result.Select(e => e is null ? default(T?) : e.Value.Item1).ToArray();
}
```

Is there a way to keep it this generic but with proper nulls instead when T is a value type? The compiler won't let me use `null` in place of `default(T?)`.

Comment: this is ultimately pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170047/why-doesnt-return-defaultt-give-a-null-when-t-is-constrained-to-enum/72170256#72170256) - just... ignore the enum bit, which the compiler already was :) ultimately, without a `T : struct` constraint, `T?` is ... woolly - it doesn't mean `Nullable<T>`; it means "`T`, but without NRT nulls" - and NRT nulls *don't apply for your case*, so: it just means: `T`

Comment: Hm, I see. In my case, T is a type parameter of the surrounding class. Would I need to duplicate the class, once with `where T : struct` and once with `where T : class` in order to support both classes and structs?

Comment: without knowing what you need to do differently in your scenario (between structs and classes), I can't comment on that; however, one pattern I've seen quite often here is to, instead of relying on nulls, to return a `(bool, T)` (or a `Maybe<T>`, or whatever you want to call it) in all cases - which is essentially like `Nullable<T>`, but it works for both classes and structs - then you don't need to differentiate

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the best way then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a `where T : struct` constraint, `T?` does **not** mean `Nullable<T>`; it means "`T`, but note that it won't be `null` in the NRT sense" - and since NRT nulls *never apply* to your value-type scenario: it basically just means `T`; and the default value of a value-type `T` is not `null` (in any sense).

In the scenario where you *need* "null checking" that crosses both value-type and reference-type scenarios *including* support for value-types without a value, then the easiest approach is usually to forget about `Nullable<T>` and just track:

1. do I have a value (`bool`), and
2. what is the value (`T`)

*separately*, and explicitly; this could be via any of:

- `bool SomeMethod(out var T)`
- `(HasValue: bool, Value: T) SomeMethod()`
- `Maybe<T> SomeMethod()`

(where `Maybe<T>` is just a custom `struct` that is composed of a `bool HasValue` and a `T Value`)

This is effectively creating something akin to `Nullable<T>`, but which applies to all values, regardless of type. Instead of checking for null, just check `.HasValue` first, and *if true*, assume that the value is meaningful.

Comment: Example of aforementioned Maybe<T> here: https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/blob/master/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/Maybe/Maybe.cs