# defining a generic implicit conversion to nullable

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, implicit-conversion

I have the following struct:

```
struct Generic<T>
{
    public T Property { get; init; }
    public Generic(T property) { Property = property; }
    public static implicit operator T?(Generic<T> x)
        => x.GetHashCode() == 42 ? null : x.Property;
}
```

The compiler underlines the `null` in the implicit conversion and reports error CS0403:

> Cannot convert `null` to type parameter `T` because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using `default(T)` instead.

But I do not define a conversion to `T`, I define it to *`T?`*! **Why does the compiler not see this?** *And what can I do to get rid of the compiler error?*

Strangely, these two nongeneric versions - one with `T` being a `struct`, one with `T` being a `class` - do not give any compiler errors:

```
struct NongenericStruct
{
    public int Property { get; init; }
    public NongenericStruct(int property) { Property = property; }
    public static implicit operator int?(NongenericStruct x)
        => x.GetHashCode() == 42 ? null : x.Property;
}

struct NongenericClass
{
    public string Property { get; init; }
    public NongenericClass(string property) { Property = property; }
    public static implicit operator string?(NongenericClass x)
        => x.GetHashCode() == 42 ? null : x.Property;
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dE78IJ) an equivalent [mre]?

Comment: `T?` is ambiguous between `struct?` and `class?` You need add a constraint.

Comment: @gunr2171 Looks equivalent to me, yes. But since I don't know what the compiler does internally, I am not sure. At least both give the same compiler error.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, your link answers my question: "There's no way that you can specify a generic parameter such that you can treat it as a class and a nullable value type." Which does not answer WHY that is so, unfortunately... Anyway, my follow-up question "What if I use default(T?) instead of null?" (which also does not work) is answered by Marc Gravell's first comment below [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72434798/5333340) question.

Answer (score 1):

A nullable reference type is not the same as a nullable value type.

As the generic type `T` has no constraint, the compiler cannot explicitly convert `null` into either a `Nullable<T>` (struct) or a `T?` (class).

In order to fix this you have to explicitly tell the compiler if it's a reference or a value type with a generic type constraint.

```cs
// reference type
where T : class

// value type
where T : struct
```

Comment: And what if I want my `Generic<T>` type to work for both `struct` and `class` `T`? Is there no other way than defining two `Generic<T>` types? If there is so much difference in that piece of code depending on `T`, why doesn't the compiler just generate two versions?

Comment: @Kjara if `Generic` was a class you could use inheritance but since it's a struct i dont thing it is an other way than 2 structs